# Multi-column unique constraint FluentNHibernate automap via convention

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping, convention

Does FluentNHibernate's automap support creating a multi-column unique constraint via convention?

I can easily create a single column unique constraint:

```
public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
{
    if(instance.Name.ToUpper().Equals("NAME"))
        instance.Unique();
}
```

With an acceptance criteria to find only `ReferenceEntity` types.

I now have an entity that I want to create a multiple column unique constraint over.  I was planing on decorating the entity's properties with an attribute to indicate they form part of the same unique key, ie:

```
public class Foo : Entity
{
    [Unique("name_parent")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [Unique("name_parent")]
    public virtual Bar Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And have the convention look for these attributes and create a unique across all fields that share the same unique key.

The `IProperyConvention` interface allows you to specify `Unique` on the specific instance (column) but without visibility over other columns.

### Update

The process of posting this helped me think through a bit more of it, so I wrote this:

```
var propertyInfo = ((PropertyInstance)(instance)).EntityType.GetMember(instance.Name).FirstOrDefault();

if (propertyInfo != null)
{
    var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

    var uniqueAttribute = attributes.OfType<UniqueAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (uniqueAttribute != null)
    {
        instance.UniqueKey(uniqueAttribute.Key);
    }
}
```

Stepping through the code it hits the `instance.UniqueKey(...)` line twice (as expected), however the constraint that is created (pgsql);

```
ADD CONSTRAINT foo_name_key UNIQUE(name);
```

When I would have expected

```
ADD CONSTRAINT name_parent UNIQUE(name, bar);
```

### Update 2

When using the `Override()` method in the AutoMap config, I can specify the correct unique keys:

```
.Override<Foo>(map => {
    map.Map(x => x.Name).UniqueKey("name_parent");
    map.Map(x => x.Description);
    map.References(x => x.Parent).UniqueKey("name_parent");
})
```

This might be an issue with the auto-mapper, not sure. Not ideal still as it isn't generic via attribute decoration, but for now the datamodel is reflecting domain requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I did this I created 2 conventions One was an AttributePropertyConvention and the other was an IReferenceConvention. My attribute looked like this:

```
public class UniqueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UniqueAttribute(string uniqueKey)
    {
        UniqueKey = uniqueKey;
    }

    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }

    public string GetKey()
    {
        return string.Concat(UniqueKey, "Unique");
    }
}
```

My property convention:

```
public class UniquePropertyConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<UniqueAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(UniqueAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.UniqueKey(attribute.GetKey());
    }
}
```

And finally the reference convention:

```
public class UniqueReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        var p = instance.Property.MemberInfo;

        if (Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(UniqueAttribute)))
        {
            var attribute = (UniqueAttribute[])p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UniqueAttribute), true);
            instance.UniqueKey(attribute[0].GetKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this works for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That works (and is essentially what I've got) but only creates a single column unique constraint.  If I specify the same name for the unique key for two different columns it doesn't include the second column in the constraint.

Comment: That's weird, because it definitely was working for me to create a unique constraint with 2 columns.

Comment: Sorry - I missed the part that this was a IReferenceConvention not an IPropertyConvention.  Works perfectly (and makes sense now that I see the IReferenceConvention bit).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.... enforce uniqueness in your domain ;)

Comment: The logic is enforced in the domain, just felt incomplete with it being enforced in the database as well.  I've updated my question with more details.  (For those being picky, this was marked as correct as JimmyP helped derive the extra details added to the question offline).